# is it possible to override an Ember.set() API?

Tags: security, ember.js

Need to override Ember.set(obj,key,value) in my application to check for vulnerable arguments for prototype pollution. Need to check if key does not have vulnerable inputs. is there a way to do it?  (Ember 2.18.0 v).

Unable to override the Ember APIs

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

let originalSet = Ember.set;

Object.defineProperty(Ember, 'set', {
  // your implementation here,
  value(obj, key, value) {
    originalSet(obj, keyValue);
  }
});
```

Using [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on MDN